# adding string in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

i am currently self-studying c++ and i am currently stuck on this problem.

I want to create a program that save Text(string) and Number(double) loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string words[999],addwords;
    double numbers[999],addnumbers;
    int totalwords=0,totalnumbers=0;
    head:
        cout << "Word: "; getline(cin,addwords);
        words[totalwords] = addwords;
        totalwords+=1;

        cout << "Numbers: "; cin >> addnumbers;
        numbers[totalnumbers] = addnumbers;
        totalnumbers+=1;
        goto head;
}
```

EOF

The output must be:
Words: Some Letters
Numbers: 010102
Words: Some Letters
Numbers: 010102
{loop}

The output of this code:
Words: Some Letters
Numbers: 010102
Words: Numbers: 202010

Thank you for help.

Comment: Edit your question to clean up the grammar please.

Comment: DONT USE GOTO!.

Comment: Please copy and paste your actual source code. What you have above clearly won't compile.

Comment: @Need4Sleep this is just sample

Comment: You can't reasonably use `getline` and `operator>>` together. One leaves newlines hanging around and the other stops upon an initial newline being read.

Comment: @chris can you explain, sorry for being noob. if i use cin on adding the name it will only get the first word. so i use getline

Comment: @MarkReyes, Most of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline+skipping) will explain it pretty well.

Comment: One word: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

In modern C++, a better practice is to use the stand-alone `getline` method, like below:

```
std::string s;

std::cout << "Enter some text:";
std::getline(cin, s);
```

If you're going to be doing this in a loop, like above, then I would also recommend using:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.sync();
```

before each next successive read, so it looks like:

```
std::cout << "Enter some more text:";
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.sync();
std::getline(cin, s);
```

There are other issues with your code beyond this, not the least of which is the use of GOTO.  What source(s) are you using to learn C++?

Comment: Some sample codes on internet. and this http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp-2004-12-19.zip

i just want to loop without statement so i goto function to make loop easier. (i just want to test add text and numbers on array)

can you explain some issues? and how can i fix this?

sorry for spoonfeeding.

Comment: It's no trouble.  I would recommend, however, that you pick up a good book or two on C++.  There are copies of the older editions of C++ books out on the web for free that would be a good start (http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html), and Stroustop's own website has good info.  (http://www.stroustrup.com) One other issue I see with your code right now, as it stands above is once you get into your `GOTO` loop you can't exit.  That's a problem.

Comment: [StackOverflow C++ book guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1)